# Make a slow monotonic injection

Tags: math, code-challenge

In 256 bytes or fewer write a function, \$f\$, from the positive integers to the positive integers that is:

- Monotonic: larger inputs always map to larger outputs. (\$a < b \implies f(a) < f(b)\$)
- Non-linear: does not have asymptotic order notation \$O(n)\$. (\$\displaystyle\forall c: \exists n:c\cdot n < f(n)\$)

Your answers will be scored by the [asymptotic Big-O order notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of the function they implement (run time is irrelevant) with smaller being better.  In the case of a tie the size of the code is the tie breaker.

You may implement a function or a complete program.  Since we are concerned with asymptotic complexity your program should accept input of arbitrary size.

Comment: So, just to understand the challenge, [this program](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TuMDh/39dYwA) would have a byte length of 4 but an O-notation (and thereby score) of: \$O(n^c)\$ where *c = 3*

Comment: Perhaps a metric what combines O(n) of the function and code length would be better? Currently it may be too easy to outscore any answer that doesn't use all 256 bytes

Comment: How are language value bit-size limitations handled? Eg. [this program](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TyjBST08vUkdbPc3RUNvh/39DAzAAAA) works, but if the `...` is repaced with `YYY`, [it breaks down](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TyjASBHS01dMcDbUd/v83NEACAA) due to the limitations on floating point numbers. *Mathematically* the second function should be 1,000,000,000 times closer to linear than the first, and every additional `Y` makes it closer still, but due to computational limits, the intermediate values exceed the available bit-space and precision is lost.

Comment: Just nitpicking: 1) Would the term *supra-linear* perhaps be better suited to the mathematical description you gave? (for example, a logarithmic function is non-linear but doesn't match the alternate definition) 2) Doesn't (strict) monotonicity (as you chose to define it using \$<\$) imply injectivity?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You will find that there is no monotonic positive integer function can be less than linear.  You are right about the injectivity though.

Comment: @Draco18s I don't know a whole lot about the specific language there, but answers should be scored on how they perform in practice when it comes to floating points.

Comment: @LuisMendo Score length is just a tie breaker I really don't intend for it to come into play very much.  It likely will be easy to outscore an answer that doesn't use all 256 bytes but I think that that is ok.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes the function's order notation.  I will try to make this extra explicit in the question.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic The important bit is that the interpreter is written in C# and does not use BigInteger or BigRational, but native data types. So a command `1Y` results in a number literal `1000` (`1` is just a `1`, `Y` is a shortcut for `ToS * 1000`). Add enough `Y`s and the number will [eventually overflow](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98wEgZUrP//BwA). This is due to the limitations imposed by hardware (no infinite memory) but which would work without those constraints. Similar thing happens on [very large inputs](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TyjBST08vUkdbPc3RUNvh/39Dg1FAOgAA).

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, one could take any answer to the duplicate and make a function `g(x) = x + f(x)`, where f(x) is the function defined in that answer, which would be a trivial answer to this question.

Comment: @pppery Actually, `g(x) = x * f(x)`.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Why does `g(x) = x + f(x)` not work? It seems that your example function would grow slightly faster than mine (but this field of math really isn't my specialty)

Comment: @pppery It is supposed to be non-linear, not just more than `x`. `f(x)` in a winning answer is most likely less than x, so `g(x)` less than `2x` which is linear.

Comment: I guess that shows my naivety at math.